# Caesar cipher not decrypting

Tags: c

When I try to decrypt a message, the output isn't what it should be. I looked up Caesar Cipher and I understand the concept, but from what I looked at everything seems to be right. Could it be that I'm using a switch statement?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>



int main(void){
   char phrase[100], option, ph;
   int key;


printf("Would you like to encrypt (e) or decrypt (d)? \n");
scanf(" %c", &option);
    printf("Enter a message (100 characters or less): \n");
scanf(" %s", phrase);

            printf("Enter key: \n");
            scanf(" %i", &key);
switch(option){
    case 'e':
     {
        for(int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; i++){
                ph = phrase[i];
                    if(ph >= 'a' && ph <= 'z'){
                        ph = ph + key;

                        if(ph > 'z'){
                            ph = ph - 'z' + 'a' - 1;
                        } //end of if
                        phrase[i] = ph;
                    } // end of if
                    else if(ph >= 'A' && ph <= 'Z'){
                        ph = ph + key;

                        if(ph > 'Z'){
                            ph = ph - 'Z' + 'A' - 1;
                        }
                        phrase[i] = ph;
                    } // end of else if
                } // end of for
                printf("Encrypted message: %s\n", phrase);
                break;
            } // end of case 'e'
    case 'd':
        { 
            for(int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; i++){
                    //~ phrase[i] = phrase[i] + 3;
                ph = phrase[i];
                    if(ph >= 'a' && ph <= 'z'){
                        ph = ph + key;

                        if(ph > 'z'){
                            ph = ph - 'z' + 'a' + 1;
                        }
                        phrase[i] = ph;
                    } // end of if
                    else if(ph >= 'A' && ph <= 'Z'){
                        ph = ph + key;

                        if(ph > 'Z'){
                            ph = ph - 'Z' + 'A' + 1;
                        } // end of if
                        phrase[i] = ph;
                    } // end of else if
                } // end of for
                printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", phrase);
                    break;
                } // end of case 'd'


    } // end of switch
} // end of function
```

GCC output for encrypting:

Would you like to encrypt (e) or decrypt (d)? 
e

Enter a message (100 characters or less): 
hello

Enter key: 
3

Encrypted message: khoor

---

GCC output for decrypting:

Would you like to encrypt (e) or decrypt (d)? 
d

Enter a message (100 characters or less): 
khoor

Enter key: 
3

Decrypted message: nkrru

---

Comment: When you decript you need to substract the key. Seems like you made a copy paste mistake(sorry for the comment answer switching)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your encryption logic and decryption logic are the same, i.e. for decryption you're adding the key when you should be subtracting.  You also need to change the overflow check for going below `'a'`:

```
case 'd':
    {
        for(int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0'; i++){
                //~ phrase[i] = phrase[i] + 3;
            ph = phrase[i];
                if(ph >= 'a' && ph <= 'z'){
                    ph = ph - key;   // subtract

                    if(ph < 'a'){    // switch wraparound check
                        ph = ph + 'z' - 'a' - 1;
                    }
                    phrase[i] = ph;
                } // end of if
                else if(ph >= 'A' && ph <= 'Z'){
                    ph = ph - key;   // subtract


                    if(ph < 'a'){    // switch wraparound check
                        ph = ph + 'Z' - 'A' - 1;
                    } // end of if
                    phrase[i] = ph;
                } // end of else if
            } // end of for
            printf("Decrypted message: %s\n", phrase);
                break;
            } // end of case 'd'
```

Comment: I thought I did that, can't believe I didn't. Thank you!

Comment: @SgtCheespuffs Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.